# What's the proper name the foo: function() style of creating a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm coming across these two ways of declaring functions in Javascript.

One is an *[assignment expression](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/)* that to declares `foo` to be whatever the function returns, i.e.

```
var foo = function(){

//do something
};
```

And the other way of declaring a function seems to make it a property of a larger object:

> foo: function() { //do something }

I'm assuming you would use the second form when you needed to access that function in an object context, i.e.:

```
myobject.foo();
```

What is the proper name for the second form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following:

```
var foo = function(){
  //do something
};
```

the right hand side is a [FunctionExpression](http://es5.github.com/#x13), it is different to a FunctionDeclaration in that the function isn't created until the code is executed, which is after function declarations have been processed and variable instatiation has occurred.

It **is not** a function declaration.

```
> foo: function() {
>  //do something
> }
```

that is also a function expression, to put it in the same form as the first:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = function(){...};
```

and it too is only created when the code is executed. There is no practical difference between the two above, use whatever seems best.

#### Edit

Oh, and in a function expression, the name is optional (and generally recommended against because of issues with IE and named function expressions).

Answer (score 3):

Both are anonymous functions, the first one assigned to a variable, the second one assigned to a property in an object literal.

Note that the *assignment expression* is just:

```
foo = something
```

The *something* happens to be an anonymous function in this case, but the term *assignment expression* is used for all assignments, not only for functions.